# Django way : ForeignKey or ManyToMany?

Tags: django, database, django-models

My partner doesn't agree with me about a common case in django.

My point of view (4 explicit tables, 1 JOIN to get roles) :

```
class Guest(models.Model):
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  email         = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class GuestRole(models.Model):
  TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Administrator'),
    (2, 'Assistant'),
    (3, 'Technician'),
  )
  guest = models.ForeignKey('Guest', null=True, related_name='roles')
  type  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)


class User(models.Model):
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  email         = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class UserRole(models.Model):
  TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Administrator'),
    (2, 'Assistant'),
    (3, 'Technician'),
  )

  user = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, related_name='roles')
  type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

His point of view (3 explicit tables + 2 hidden tables, 2 JOIN to get roles) :

```
class Guest(models.Model):
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  email         = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
  role          = models.ManyToMany('Role')

class User(models.Model):
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  email         = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  role          = models.ManyToMany('Role')

class Role(models.Model):
  label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

(A Guest is invited by a User and become a User if he accepts the invitation)

Anyway, what is the Django way for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea:

```
class RoleInfo(models.Model):
  TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Administrator'),
    (2, 'Assistant'),
    (3, 'Technician'),
  )
  type  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Guest(RoleInfo):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)

class User(RoleInfo):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Basically, your first example is OK, but you use the same code twice. Your second example is like what I wrote, but a little bit worse as you will create a `Role` table in your DB and create instances of `Role` class also, is this what you really want?

If you want to use the same piece of code in many models you can use Abstract classes or Proxy classes. As you need to add a new field to your `Guest` and `User` creating of an abstract model is the best variant.

[More about abstract models.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: Abstract class is a good option for field deduplication but in your example, I can have only one role for each user/guest, no ? so it's not exactly the same thing that my example. So you think that code deduplication (manyToMany) is better than query optimisation (ForeignKey) ?

Comment: @frlinw If you want more complicated roles with  opportunities to make some relations you can take a look at [django's permissions models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/15ef1dd478c5b6f005e5f782b7619f718ed55e84/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L207) as it is almost the same as your `Role` class. They use a mixin with m2m relation to a single `Permision` model.